# Every open ball in a metric space is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Theorem:Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$ and $r >0$. Then the open ball $B(x,r)=\{y \in X :d(x,y) <r\}$ is an open set.

Now if we consider X to be set of all integers under usual metric, then we can find the open balls using the usual metric but those open balls will not be open sets (according to definition: every point is an interior point.}. So how to justify this theorem?

Comment: The theorem doesn't make sense unless you specify a topology. What are the open sets to begin with...

Comment: I do not know if this is your doubt but from this definition one can conclude that $\mathbb{Z}$ is opened in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If by usual metric on the integers you mean the one induced by the Euclidean metric, then the resulting topology is discrete. Every set is open.

Comment: "but those open balls will not be open sets (according to definition: every point is an interior point"  But they *are* open sets and every point *is* an interior point....  Example $B(5,\frac 14)=\{y\in \mathbb Z: d(5,y)< \frac 14\} = \{5\}$.  for any $\epsilon: 0< \epsilon < 1$ we have $B(5,\epsilon) = \{5\}\subset \{5\}$ so $5$ ***IS*** an interior point of $\{5\}$.

Comment: FWIW IMO this is not a duplicate.  The OP is not asking for why the theorem is true, but for why their example is not a counter example..... which isn't to say this question hasn't been asked before (I remember seeing it several times); just that the cited question is a different question than this one.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is the integers then $B(n, 1) = \{y \in \Bbb Z: |n-y| < 1\}=\{n\}$ as integers are at least $1$ apart. And all singletons are open sets in $(\Bbb Z, d)$ so there is no problem.

Comment: Please check for duplicates before duplicating answers to previous questions already asked and answered.